# Why does my image not change color correctly?

Tags: java

I was trying to change a color in my BufferedImage using this function:

```
public LoadedImage replaceColor(Color color1, Color color2) {
        for (int y = 0; y < this.image.getHeight(); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < this.image.getWidth(); x++) {
                int pixel = this.image.getRGB(x, y);
                Color col = new Color(pixel);
                
                if (col.getRGB() == color1.getRGB()) {
                    this.image.setRGB(x, y, color2.getRGB());
                }
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
```

(this.image is the BufferedImage, this is a class that contains the BufferedImage)

This is the result that I get:
[image]

This is the result I want:
[image]

This is the image I am using:
[image]

(the gray is the background btw)

Why doesn't this work? The image gives different results when I change it to green or blue.

Here is the code that I am using:

```java
BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("img/" + image));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        Color color1 = new Color(255, 255, 255, 255); 
        Color color2 = new Color(255, 0, 0, 255);
        
        for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++) {
                int pixel = img.getRGB(x, y);

                Color col = new Color(pixel);
                
                if (col.getRGB() == color1.getRGB()) {
                    img.setRGB(x, y, color2.getRGB());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'd use painting software to create the images and create the images in all the colors I want to use so my application just has to shuffle images.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show the original image, along with the method call

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that..

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong What do you mean by method call? I just call the method like this:

Comment: img.replaceColor(new Color(255,255,255,255), new Color(255, 0, 0));

Comment: using the newly added image from question and the call as given above (should have been included in the question) I got [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kflkl.png) : seems like the desired output, the problem is somewhere else, posted code seems good. Maybe how the image is being saved or checked...

Comment: @user16320675 I tried redrawing the image but I get the same result. For me, it only works when the background is not transparent, but why is that? This is the method I use for loading my image:

Comment: public static LoadedImage loadImage(String image) {
  BufferedImage img = null;
  try {
   img = ImageIO.read(new File("img/" + image));
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  
  return new LoadedImage(img);
 }

Comment: @user16320675 I added some more code. That's basically all the code for the image loading and color replacing. I just use Graphics2D.drawImage to draw it in my game's window.

Comment: @user16320675 That's odd.. if I use a different image then that image works? Is it the size of the image that's making it not work?

Comment: I used the same code and I used the message diologue code, but it still doesn't work? https://i.imgur.com/L0MQN7s.png

Comment: Also, my image is 28x36 pixels..

Comment: @user16320675 My code works with the bigger picture. Is there any way I can make it work with the smaller image?